# Erlang noproc error when trying to terminate child process

Tags: erlang

I tried to design one server to start temporary process when it receives request. However when I tried to terminate or kill the temporary process, I got `noproc` error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

I got the following files:

temp.erl (main supervisor)

```
-module(temp).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).
-export([list_children/0]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

list_children() ->
    supervisor:which_children(?MODULE).

init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    io:format("****Main supervisor****~n"),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 5, 10}, 
          [{temp_srv, {temp_srv, start_link, []}, 
            permanent, infinity, worker, [temp_srv]}, 
           {temp_sup, {temp_sup, start_link, []}, 
            permanent, infinity, supervisor, [temp_sup]}]}}.
```

temp_srv.erl (server)

```
-module(temp_srv).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, handle_call/3, terminate/2, code_change/3]).
-export([start_link/0, echo_call/1]).

-record(state, {}).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

echo_call(Data) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, {echo, Data}).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_call({echo, Data}, _From, State) ->
    Result = temp_sup:assign_task({echo, Data}),
    {reply, Result, State};
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(_Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_Old, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

temp_sup.erl (supervisor to start temporary process)

```
-module(temp_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).
-export([start_temp_worker/0, list_children/0, assign_task/1, select_available_children/1, select_finished_children/1]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

list_children() ->
        supervisor:which_children(?MODULE).

init([]) ->
    io:format("****Temp supervisor*****~n"),
    spawn_link(fun start_pool/0),
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 0, 1}, [{temp_worker, {temp_worker, start_link, []}, temporary, 1000, worker, [temp_worker]}]}}.

start_pool() ->
        [start_temp_worker() || _ <- lists:seq(1, 3)].

start_temp_worker() ->
        supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).

assign_task(Data) ->
        case list_children() of
                [] ->
                        {ok, Pid} = start_temp_worker(),
                        gen_server:call(Pid, Data);
                ChildL when is_list(ChildL) ->
            case select_finished_children(ChildL) of
                no_pid_to_kill -> ok;
                {ok, KPid} -> gen_server:call(KPid, stop)
            end,
            {ok, Pid} = select_available_children(ChildL),
            start_temp_worker(),
            io:format("Assign task to ~p~n", [Pid]),
            gen_server:call(Pid, Data)
        end.

select_available_children([ChildH | ChildT]) ->
    {undefined, Pid, worker, [temp_worker]} = ChildH,
    case gen_server:call(Pid, check_status) of
        active -> 
            io:format("Find available children ~p~n", [Pid]),
            {ok, Pid};
        running -> select_available_children(ChildT);
        done -> select_available_children(ChildT)
    end.

select_finished_children([ChildH | ChildT]) ->
    {undefined, KPid, worker, [temp_worker]} = ChildH,
    case gen_server:call(KPid, check_status) of
        done -> 
            io:format("Find process ~p to kill~n", [KPid]),
            {ok, KPid};
        _ -> select_finished_children(ChildT)
    end;
select_finished_children([]) -> no_pid_to_kill.
```

temp_worker.erl (temporary process)

```
-module(temp_worker).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).
-export([handle_info/2, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, code_change/3, terminate/2]).
-record(state, {status}).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    io:format("Start temporary worker process ~p~n", [self()]),
    {ok, #state{status = active}}.

handle_info(_Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_call(check_status, _From, #state{status = Status} = State) ->
    {reply, Status, State};
handle_call({echo, Msg}, _From, State) ->
    io:format("~p get echo request for message ~p~n", [self(), Msg]),
    {reply, Msg, State#state{status = done}};
handle_call(stop, _From, State) ->
    {stop, normal, stopped, State};
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(_Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

code_change(_Old, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.
```

The design is supposed to start three temporary process once the temporary supervisor starts, once it receives request, it will terminate one temporary process which has finished work.

That's how I run these code:

```
9> temp:start_link().      
****Main supervisor****
****Temp supervisor*****
Start temporary worker process <0.98.0>
{ok,<0.94.0>}
Start temporary worker process <0.99.0>
Start temporary worker process <0.101.0>
10> temp_srv:echo_call(asd).
Find available children <0.98.0>
Start temporary worker process <0.102.0>
Assign task to <0.98.0>
<0.98.0> get echo request for message asd
asd
11> temp_srv:echo_call(asd).
Find process <0.98.0> to kill

=ERROR REPORT==== 23-May-2017::23:16:34 ===
** Generic server temp_srv terminating 
** Last message in was {echo,asd}
** When Server state == {state}
** Reason for termination == 
** {{noproc,{gen_server,call,[<0.98.0>,check_status]}},
    [{gen_server,call,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,204}]},
     {temp_sup,select_available_children,1,[{file,"temp_sup.erl"},{line,41}]},
     {temp_sup,assign_task,1,[{file,"temp_sup.erl"},{line,33}]},
     {temp_srv,handle_call,3,[{file,"temp_srv.erl"},{line,21}]},
     {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,615}]},
     {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,647}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 23-May-2017::23:16:34 ===
** Generic server temp terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.92.0>,
                           {{{noproc,
                                 {gen_server,call,[<0.98.0>,check_status]}},
                             {gen_server,call,[temp_srv,{echo,asd}]}},
                            [{gen_server,call,2,
                                 [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,204}]},
                             {erl_eval,do_apply,6,
                                 [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
                             {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                             {shell,eval_exprs,7,
                                 [{file,"shell.erl"},{line,641}]},
                             {shell,eval_loop,3,
                                 [{file,"shell.erl"},{line,626}]}]}}
** When Server state == {state,
                            {local,temp},
                            one_for_one,
                            [{child,<0.96.0>,temp_sup,
                                 {temp_sup,start_link,[]},
                                 permanent,infinity,supervisor,
                                 [temp_sup]},
                             {child,<0.104.0>,temp_srv,
                                 {temp_srv,start_link,[]},
                                 permanent,infinity,worker,
                                 [temp_srv]}],
                            undefined,5,10,
                            [-576459529],
                            0,temp,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {{{noproc,{gen_server,call,[<0.98.0>,check_status]}},
     {gen_server,call,[temp_srv,{echo,asd}]}},
    [{gen_server,call,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,204}]},
     {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
     {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
     {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,641}]},
     {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,626}]}]}
** exception exit: {{noproc,{gen_server,call,[<0.98.0>,check_status]}},
                    {gen_server,call,[temp_srv,{echo,asd}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 204)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [error docs](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html):

> noproc -- Trying to link to a non-existing process.

The error message says the problematic line is:

```
case gen_server:call(Pid, check_status) of
```

That means Pid is is a non-existent process. In your output, you can see:

```
Assign task to <0.98.0>
<0.98.0> get echo request for message asd
asd
```

I think that means process <0.98.0> has finished executing and has terminated.  You can verify that by outputting `process_info(Pid)`, which will return `undefined` for a non-existent process.  That process is at the head of your `ChildL` list.  You can verify that with an `io:format()` statement:

```
    assign_task(Data) ->
        ...
        case select_finished_children(ChildL) of
            no_pid_to_kill -> ok;
            {ok, KPid} -> gen_server:call(KPid, stop)
        end,
        io:format("assign_task(): ChildL: ~w~n", [ChildL]),  %%<***HERE
        io:format("****Info: ~w~n", [process_info(Pid)]),    %%<***HERE
        {ok, Pid} = select_available_children(ChildL),
```

Then your code does this:

```
select_available_children([ChildH | ChildT]) ->
    {undefined, Pid, worker, [temp_worker]} = ChildH,
    case gen_server:call(Pid, check_status) of
```

`ChildH` contains the pid `<0.98.0>`, which has terminated, and that pid gets bound to `Pid`.  Then `gen_server:call(Pid)` executes, which results in a `noproc` error.

Comment: I used process_info to check the process, the result shows the process is still alive, its status is waiting.

Comment: @billcyz, Come on now.  After it said the status was waiting, there wasn't an error.

Comment: When did you checked the process? If you checked after erlang crashes, then you won't find anything, event its supervisor is gone.

Comment: @billcyz, Add the lines I showed, run your code exactly as you did in your question, find the error message in the output, scroll up to the first line of the error, then tell me what the first line prior to the first line of the error message says?

Comment: The problem is solved. I think the child list causes the problem. I changed my code to : assign_task(Data) ->
        case select_finished_children(list_children()) of
                no_pid_to_kill -> ok;
                {ok, KPid} -> stopped = gen_server:call(KPid, stop)
        end,  The problem is sovled.